# iPhone backup symlink to external drive doesn't work after creation

Tags: backup, symlink

I made an iPhone backup on my MacBook and then copied the backup folder to an external drive. I then created a symlink between the two using the following terminal command:

```
ln -s /Volumes/'TOSHIB EXT'/backup_s/ ~/Library/'Application Support'/MobileSync/Backup/268b0bab3dbd3425c578030c6fc7309a3a83dcd9
```

This created a symlink file in my backup directory.

My goal was to delete the backup files from my local machine and just connect the external drive whenever I wanted to backup my iPhone so that I could save space on the MacBook.

However, after creating this symlink, I did a backup of the iPhone to test it out and, for some reason, while the backup on the MacBook does update (as indicated by the time of last modification), the copy in the external drive remains unaffected.

Can anyone suggest a fix?

Comment: I've noticed that my Mac has several backup folders (named with random alphanumeric characters) in `Backup`, could it be that the iPhone backup was created in a new subfolder (not the one you symlinked)? If you create a symlink to `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup`, does it work? How did you copy the backup folder, using the Finder or Terminal? If you used Terminal, I'd recommend that you copy it again using the Finder.

Comment: @jaume Hello, I checked if the backup was in a new folder and it wasn't the case. I did try making a symlink to ```~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup``` but that didn't do much either. I copied the folder by just dragging it to the drive, I suppose thats finder.